# Excel Direct vs Indirect Cash Flow: Identify Cells that are not being used in both methods

Tags: vba, excel, modeling, finance

I work on various financial models created on Excel that produce forecasted financial reports. One of the key reports is the statement of cash flows. Traditionally the [Indirect Method](http://www.accountingtools.com/cash-flows-indirect-method) of cash flows is the one that has been needed to produce, but the [Direct Method](http://www.accountingtools.com/cash-flows-direct-method) has become necessary for some clients. In an ideal world you would want both of these methods to show the same result.

Given that these reports are not always created by the same individual I have to find accounts (Cells) considered in one method and make sure they are considered in the other method to track differences.

---

Example: Exports for 10,000 (Cell B3 - Sheet Sales)

In the Indirect Method

- This account goes to the P&L. It is used to calculate the Operating Revenue (Cell B10 - Sheet P&L)
- The Operating Revenue goes to the Cash Flow and is used to find the Operating Cash Flow. (Cell B50 - Sheet Indirect Cash Flow)
- The Operating Cash Flows finally determines the Total Cash (Cell B100 - Sheet Indirect Cash Flow)

In the Direct Method

- This account goes directly to the sales to find the Operating Cash Flows (Cell B80 - Sheet Direct Cash Flow)
- The Operating Cash Flows finally determines the Total Cash (Cell B120 - Sheet Direct Cash Flow)

Both Cell B100 (Sheet Indirect Cash Flow) and Cell B120 (Sheet Direct Cash Flow) should be equal and the difference should be the sum of all those accounts that are used on one of the methods but not the other.

---

In this case the value of the cell is considered in both methods it does not need further work. However, in the case that one account is not found on one of the methods I have to model it in or out depending on the case.

So basically I want to find a way to identify in a set of cell which are being considered for cash flow purposes and of those accounts which are missing on one of the methods.

I am trying to find a best way to approach the problem and if someone has already applied a solution to a similar case all the better. Ideally I should use a separate workbook to query each sheet in the model so I can use a Macro, VBA, or In-Cell formulae.

Comment: If/when you do this manually, what do you do? Look into the formula for Indirect Method - Operating Revenue to identify the cells used there? Look into the formula for Direct Method - Operating Cash Flows to identify the cells used there? Identify a mismatch?

Comment: I take an account in the Direct Cash Flow to audit where the value comes from. Check first level precedent(s), which takes me to a different sheet, I check if it has dependents going into the P&L, Balance Sheet, or Indirect. If not, I go to the next level precedent, and check for the same. Once I find it (P&L or Balance Sheet) I follow the path to see if it ends up in Indirect.

Comment: @OldUgly If I identify a mismatch I have to decide which once is wrong before modeling it in.  If I start with the indirect is a bit more complicated because the accounts there are more condensed (meaning one account has many more cells being added together). Hope my answer help you understand better?

Comment: Would it be possible to ask if two cells have a precedent in common? It sounds more like an audit feature that Excel should have rather than anything else.